# Do we have an API for airdrop

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin, airdrop

I am creating an news app which will show the ICO and Airdrop details. Is there is any API for Airdrop news ?

Comment: You gotta be the first one who create such API. There are some sites like airdropalert.com which collecting airdrops, but no API

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is https://coinmarketcal.com which keeps track, you can also filter to get only airdrops.

They also have an API: https://api.coinmarketcal.com/

Comment: nothing I could see in https://api.coinmarketcal.com/

Comment: @iappmaker on the bottom it says "Events" and "Categories" which are the respective APIs for that

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in airdrop in ethereum. You could do a smart contract  that airdrops tokens, check github for "ERC airdrop"!
 https://github.com/indorseio/airdrop/blob/master/indorser.sol

Comment: https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender/#/ - or this is the Dapp that people use for airdrops

Comment: Notice the limit of destination addresses is 150 because of the gaz fees

Comment: because of block limit to 8M

Comment: There is always Dapple Airdrops! https://www.dappleairdrops.com/

Comment: Yes but as you see even there it's 150 destinations MAX,the gas limit issue still apply!